# Multi Module Spring Boot Dependency issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a maven multi module Spring boot project
------------Module A 
------------Module B

**Module A** has the Main Class and **Module B** has **Module A** as dependency .

***Issue***-Spring is not scanning Module B Components.

***Assuming***-I cannot add Module B as dependency in Module A pom.xml due to circular dependency.

Comment: why not create main in Module B and from here start spring context?